# All my information is erased when I reset GoogleAppEngine. How can't i avoid this?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have some problemas with Datastore.
when i restart googleappengine all my data is deleted.

i don't know Why my data is deleted when restart AppEngine ?

what can't i do?

Comment: What do you mean by, "restart googleappengine?" Are you using the Launcher? Are you running `dev_appserver.py` from the command line? We need more information.

Comment: when I turn off my laptop and the next day I open eclipse and run my application I see nothing of what used to store

Comment: Are you using `--clear_datastore`?

Comment: By default, the data is stored in /tmp; either specify a different location on the commandline or stop your computer from clearing tempfiles on restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fixed in 1.6.6.  @Erikson Murrugarra: please update your SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the 1.6.6 SDK on Windows, we're aware of the problem, and it'll be fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: Hey, wasn't this a problem in 1.6.4 an 1.6.5 but fixed in 1.6.6?

Comment: I know we fixed it. I may have the numbers off by one.